# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/oltu/oauth2/client/request/OAuthClientRequest$TokenRequestBuilder

Tags: android, junit, mockito, swagger, dagger-2

Below mentioned error occurred while running Junit .

> Architecture of app in same as 
>   https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate

I have used swagger-codegen to generate my client code for retrofit

**Test Case**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginPresenterTest {
    @Mock
    LoginView loginView;
    @Mock
    DataClient dataClient;

    private LoginPresenter loginPresenter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        loginPresenter = new LoginPresenter();
        loginPresenter.attachView(loginView);

    }

    @Test
    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        loginPresenter.doLogin("abc", "abc");
    }
}
```

Can some one help me to find out the cause .

**Error Log**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/oltu/oauth2/client/request/OAuthClientRequest$TokenRequestBuilder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:349)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:352)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:422)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:457)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:123)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:66)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:55)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.withBefores(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.request.OAuthClientRequest$TokenRequestBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: @DownVoters please mention the reason for down vote

Answer (score 2):

Your client side **misses** "Apache Oltu OAuth 2.0 Client" dependency and thus the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/oltu/oauth2/client/request/OAuthClientRequest$TokenRequestBuilder

For Gradle Build use:

`compile 'org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:1.0.1'`

For Maven use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```